# Incomplete type in friend function

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, friend, incomplete-type

This is a mcve of my code: (if it matters, `Options_proxy` and `Options` have constexpr ctors). I am aware it's still far from simple, but couldn't simplify it more while still exhibiting the error:

```
template <class Impl>
struct Options_proxy : Impl {
  using Flag = typename Impl::Flag;

  friend constexpr auto operator!(Flag f) -> Options_proxy {
    return {}; // <-- error here
  };
};

template <class Impl>
struct Options : Impl {
  using Flag = typename Impl::Flag;
};

struct File_options_impl {
  enum class Flag : unsigned { nullflag, read, write  };

  friend constexpr auto operator!(Flag f) -> Options_proxy<File_options_impl>;
};

using File_options = Options<File_options_impl>;

auto foo()
{
  !File_options::Flag::write; // <-- required from here
}
```

gcc 6 and 7 give this error:

```
In instantiation of 'constexpr Options_proxy<File_options_impl> operator!(Options_proxy<File_options_impl>::Flag)':
required from ... etc etc...
error: return type 'struct Options_proxy<File_options_impl>' is incomplete
```

clang compiles it OK.

The code complies in gcc if:

- I remove the `constexpr` of the `operator!`

or

- add an object of type `Options_proxy<File_options_impl>` before the operator call:

like this:

```
auto foo()
{
  Options_proxy<File_options_impl> o;
  !File_options::Flag::write; // <-- now OK in gcc also
}
```

Is this a gcc bug or is some Undefined Behavior in the code, something like unspecified or no diagnostics required?

---

As for motivation of writing such code:

I want to create (for fun mostly) a type safe flag/options system (without macros):

Library black magic:

```
template <class Impl>
  requires Options_impl<Impl>
struct Options : Impl {
   // go crazy
};
```

User code:

```
struct File_options_impl {
  // create a system where here the code
  // needs to be as minimal as possible to avoid repetition and user errors

  // this is what the user actually cares about
  enum class Flag : unsigned { nullflag = 0, read = 1, write = 2, create = 4};

  // would like not to need to write this,
  // but can't find a way around it
  friend constexpr auto operator!(Flag f1) -> Options_proxy<File_options_impl>;
  friend constexpr auto operator+(Flag f1, Flag f2) -> Options_proxy<File_options_impl>;
  friend constexpr auto operator+(Flag f1, Options_proxy<File_options_impl> f2) -> Options_proxy<File_options_impl>;
};

using File_options = Options<File_options_impl>;
```

and then:

```
auto open(File_options opts);

using F_opt = File_options::Flag;
open(F_opt::write + !F_opt::create);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a gcc bug. Here's an MCVE (4 lines):

```
struct X;
template<int> struct A { friend constexpr A f(X*) { return {}; } };
// In instantiation of 'constexpr A<0> f(X*)':
// error: return type 'struct A<0>' is incomplete
struct X { friend constexpr A<0> f(X*); };
auto&& a = f((X*)0);
```

This is accepted by clang and MSVC.

As you have observed, gcc accepts the same program without `constexpr`, or if you explicitly instantiate `A<0>` (e.g. with `template struct A<0>;`) before `auto&& a = f((X*)0);`. This suggests that the problem gcc is having is in class template implicit instantiation **[temp.inst]**:

> 1 - Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly instantiated (14.7.2) or explicitly specialized (14.7.3),
>   the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context
>   that requires a completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics
>   of the program.

The class template `A<0>` is required at the `return` statement of `constexpr A<0> f(X*)`, so should be implicitly instantiated at that point. Although the friend function definition is lexically within the class `A`, the class should not be considered to be incomplete within the definition of the friend function; e.g. the following non-template program is universally accepted:

```
struct Y;
struct B { friend constexpr B f(Y*) { return {}; } };
struct Y { friend constexpr B f(Y*); };
auto&& b = f((Y*)0);
```

Interestingly, both gcc *and* clang (though not MSVC) have trouble with the following program (again, fixed by removing `constexpr` or explicitly instantiating with `template struct C<0>;`):

```
struct Z;
template<int> struct C { friend constexpr C* f(Z*) { return 0; } };
struct Z { friend constexpr C<0>* f(Z*); };
// error: inline function 'constexpr C<0>* f(Z*)' used but never defined
auto&& c = f((Z*)0);
```

I would suggest using the explicit-instantiation workaround. In your case that would be:

```
template class Options_proxy<File_options_impl>;
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see with your code is that multiple implementations may have the same ::Flag member, meaning your friend operator potentially gets defined multiple times, violating the one definition rule.

Also Options_proxy does not have any private members, so you don't need to make the operator a friend (I think you're abusing friend to define an external function inline).

You need an unambiguous definition for your operator and I don't think it's possible with the current signature.

---

Given a guarantee that Flags are unique, you could try to move the operator outside of Options_proxy.

```
template <class Impl>
struct Options_proxy : Impl {
  using Flag = typename Impl::Flag;
};

template <class Impl, typename Flag = Impl::Flag>
constexpr Options_proxy<Impl> operator!(Flag f) {
  return {};
}

template <class Impl>
struct Options : Impl {
  using Flag = typename Impl::Flag;
};

struct File_options_impl {
  enum class Flag : unsigned { nullflag, read, write  };

  friend constexpr Options_proxy<File_options_impl> operator!(Flag f);
  // Or if that doesn't work:
  friend constexpr Options_proxy<File_options_impl> operator!<File_options_impl>(Flag f);
};
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. 1. separate specialization will have different `Flag` members. They can end up having the same `Flag` if `Impl::Flag` is an alias. That won't happen in the current system. 2. As I've said this is a mcve, so the real code is far more complex. I agree that it is a bit of an abuse of friend declaration, but I don't see any other way to define operators for `Flag` outside of `File_options_impl` (in the library part of the code). 3. I am not so sure it's not possible. I would be very disappointed if it weren't possible.